# How to unhighlight visual assist x highlighted find result?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-assist

Visual assist x is able to highlight the find result, It is useful while I am searching for the right result. But after I got the right one, it is useless. Then how could I unhighlight the result?

Answer (score 1):

Press ESC within a source window.